# Spring escapes already escaped string

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

So I have this string that I am saving in database:

```
{\"facebook\":\"fb.com\",\"twitter\":\"twitter.com\",\"instagram\":\"\",\"googlePlus\":\"\",\"others\":\"espn.com\"}
```

But when I call the GET api, I get this in JSON

```
{\\\"facebook\\\":\\\"fb.com\\\",\\\"twitter\\\":\\\"twitter.com\\\",\\\"instagram\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"googlePlus\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"others\\\":\\\"espn.com\\\"}
```

Why is this happening and how can I get the exact same data that is stored in database?

Answer (score 6):

It is escaped again when you're retrieving the data because Spring thinks that the `\` character is part of the data and not used to escape `"`.

You never want to store escaped characters (be it for JSON special characters, HTML characters in a text, ...), you have to store unescaped data to fix your issue. Escaping has to be done when displaying data, not when storing it.

It is a bad practice to store escaped data because of the problem you're having but also because it will take useless storage space in the database (which might not be a problem right now for you, but will be with millions of rows).

Answer (score 1):

You could also use apache's build in `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(String input)`  mechanism for Json data. See reference https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html

Comment: I am using this to unescape the string before saving it to database.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the data, save it in a `String` and then :

```
 String newJava = str.replace("\\\", "\");
```